# The completion of a ring R is a domain then the ring R is a domain?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

Let be R a commutative ring whit unit and let I a proper ideal of R. Let R' the completion of R respect to the ideal I (see Introduction to Commutative Algebra - M. F. Atiyah, I. G. MacDonald for the definition). It's true or false that:

> R' is an integral domain then R is an integral domain?

Comment: Well, you need some hypothesis since completion only sees things locally. (Take the disjoint union of two lines $R = k[x] \times k[y]$ and complete wrt a maximal ideal on one of the lines but not the other).

Comment: Is $R$ a local ring?

Comment: hm - I remember being given this as a homework problem, and given the way it's stated it certainly smells like one...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. $\mathbb{Z}/6$ completed at the prime $(3)$ is $\mathbb{Z}/3$. (I can think of true versions of this statment, but I'll hold off until it's clearer what you're looking for.)

Comment: Please, could you elaborate on "I can think of true versions of this statement"?

Comment: @user237522 If $R$ is a noetherian local ring, then $R$ injects in $R'$. So, in this situation, if $R'$ is an integral domain, then so is $R$.

Comment: Thank you very much!